# running Ubuntu 15.04 how do I gain root privileges for nmap?

Tags: permissions, 15.04

I am a long time user of Ubuntu but recently have begun to gain a growing interest in the programming potential of the OS. I recently installed nmap and am trying to learn about the interface and how it works. But when ever I run the following command:

```
nmap -O -v scanme.nmap.org
```

as per 'https://nmap.org/book/osdetect-usage.html' example the rejection comes up as:

```
TCP/IP fingerprinting (for OS scan) requires root privileges. QUITTING!
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run it with sudo in front -  `sudo nmap -O -v scanme.nmap.org`

When you're asked for a password enter the one of your user.

Comment: Thank you oh so very much!!! It worked flawlessly!! Do you recommend that I use Sudo every time, I assume that I should but it's better to ask then assume.

Comment: No need to use it every time. In fact it might be bad in some situations, so the best thing you can do is use it only when required. Most apps run fine without it.